# Altering URL for Spring Security SAML2 Login

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0

I have an application with multiple authentication types (i.e. Basic and a special Preauthorized login). I am attempting to add a SAML2 RelyingParty registration in my security configuration, where I am attempting to change the default path from:

`/login/saml2/sso/{registrationId}`
to
`/auth/saml2/{registrationId}`

So, I have the following setup:

```
    public RelyingPartyRegistration provder1RelyingPartyRegistration() {

        RelyingPartyRegistration registration = RelyingPartyRegistrations
                .fromMetadataLocation("classpath:provider1/metadata.xml")
                .registrationId("provider1")
                .assertionConsumerServiceLocation("{baseUrl}/auth/saml2/{registrationId}")
                .build();


        return registration;
    }

    // @Bean
    public RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository() {

        Collection<RelyingPartyRegistration> registrations = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(provider1RelyingPartyRegistration()));

        InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository repository = new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(registrations);

        return repository;
    }

// fluff

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        final RequestMatcher filterRequestMatcher = new OrRequestMatcher(
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/basic"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/preauth")
        );

        ApplicationAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new ApplicationAuthenticationProcessingFilter(filterRequestMatcher, authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler());

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(filter, LogoutFilter.class)
                // fluff
                .and()
        .saml2Login()
            .relyingPartyRegistrationRepository(relyingPartyRegistrationRepository())
            .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/saml2/{registrationId}")
        ;
    }
```

Unfortunately, I get this:

```
14 Dec 10:55:34  WARN [https-openssl-nio-127.0.0.1-444-exec-2] (DispatcherServlet.java:1278) - No mapping for POST /svc/auth/saml2/provider1
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong trying to change that path? My application does NOT use Spring Boot, so I'm stuck with manual configuration.

**EDIT**

Some debugging has led to this hitting this line in the `Saml2LoginConfigurer`:

```
            Map<String, String> providerUrlMap = getIdentityProviderUrlMap(
                    this.authenticationRequestEndpoint.filterProcessingUrl, this.relyingPartyRegistrationRepository);
```

Somehow, there's a default `authenticationRequestEndpoint` (since I didn't define one) setting the `filterProcessingUrl` to a value of `/saml2/authenticate/{registrationId}`. So, how do I override this?

Comment: Can you add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` and see if there's anything in the logs? Also, please place a breakpoint inside `Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter` and see if the request comes in

Comment: I'm actually right in the middle of doing that. The request hits on ```doFilterInternal()``` for that, and bypasses the filter because of a check against an ```AntRequestMatcher``` which by default is ```"/saml2/authenticate/{registrationId}"```. This is set with a method named ```setRedirectMatcher()``` but setting that doesn't seem to be an option in ```saml2login()``` in the ```configure()``` method.

Comment: When you set the `loginProcessingUrl` the `Saml2LoginConfigurer` should pass the value to the `Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter`. Can you debug `Saml2LoginConfigurer#init` method and see which value for `loginProcessingUrl` it is using?

Comment: I just posted an edit, there's some automatic configuration stuff going on that I'm not sure how to override.

Answer (score 3):

The `loginProcessingUrl` is called by the asserting party after the authentication succeeds, which contains in the request the `SAMLResponse` parameter.

What you are trying to change is the URL to process an authentication request (create the `SAMLRequest` and send to the asserting party), this is done by the `Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter` class. To change the `redirectMatcher` you have to provide an `ObjectPostProcessor`, see [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8552).

```java
ObjectPostProcessor<Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter> processor = new ObjectPostProcessor<>() {
        @Override
        public <O extends Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter> O postProcess(O filter) {
            filter.setRedirectMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/my/custom/url"));
            return filter;
        }
};
http.saml2Login().addObjectPostProcessor(processor);
```

Take a look at [SAML 2.0 Login Overview](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/overview.html) for more detail about the flow.

Comment: setRedirectMatcher is deprecated and was removed in Spring Security 6